# How to apply filter based on purely matching condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server

From below table I want to filter employee which are purely sitting on category "1"

```
+---------+----------+
| EMPNAME | Category |
+---------+----------+
| aaa     |        1 |
| aaa     |        2 |
| aaa     |        3 |
| bbb     |        2 |
| bbb     |        3 |
| ccc     |        1 |
| ddd     |        1 |
| ddd     |        2 |
| eee     |        1 |
| fff     |        3 |
| ggg     |        2 |
| hhh     |        1 |
| hhh     |        2 |
| hhh     |        3 |
| iii     |        2 |
| jjj     |        3 |
| kkk     |        1 |
+---------+----------+
```

Tried where clause but employee `aaa` will also comes in result which is false.

Comment: so what's this ? aaa 1

Comment: aaa is the employee name which is having category 1 , 2 and 3

Comment: what is your expected result..

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from yourtable t1
where not exists
(
    select 1
    from yourtable t2
    where t1.EMPNAME=t2.EMPNAME
    and t2.Category<>1
)
```

Comment: The `Category = 1` is actually not needed.

Answer (score 1):

Using `EXCEPT`:

```
SELECT EMPNAME
FROM table
WHERE Category = 1

EXCEPT

SELECT EMPNAME
FROM table
WHERE Category <> 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `group by` and having `count()`

```
select * from table1 where empname in (select empname from table1 
group by empname 
having count(category) = 1) and category = 1
```